# Integrating Unity+Vuforia to existing iOS project make user interaction not working

Tags: swift, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Currently I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity/issues/65) to integrate Unity+Vuforia project to my existing iOS project. I manage to be able to show the Unity view inside my ARViewController. The thing is I lost all the user interaction in my view controller: my touch event for back button not fire up.

```
import Foundation

class ARViewController: UIViewController {

    var unityView: UIView?

    static func instantiateViewController() -> ARViewController {
        let controller = UIStoryboard.main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ARViewController") as! ARViewController
        return controller
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appDelegate.currentUnityController = UnityAppController()
            appDelegate.currentUnityController?.application(UIApplication.shared, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: nil)
            appDelegate.startUnity()
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleUnityReady), name: NSNotification.Name("UnityReady"), object: nil)
        }

    }

    @IBAction func onBackPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            appDelegate.stopUnity()
        }
    }

    @objc func backPressedTest() {
    }

    @objc func handleUnityReady() {
        showUnitySubView()
    }

    func showUnitySubView() {

        guard let unityView = UnityGetGLView() else { return }

        self.unityView = unityView
        // insert subview at index 0 ensures unity view is behind current UI view
        view?.addSubview(unityView)

        unityView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let views = ["view": unityView]
        let w = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-0-[view]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
        let h = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-50-[view]-0-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
        view.addConstraints(w + h)

        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_back_black").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(backPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 28, height: 60)
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: button.frame.width).isActive = true
        button.tintColor = UIColor.purpleBrown()
        view?.addSubview(button)

    }
}
```

I also notice that button from Unity also have any effect when I touch it. The back button inside the green bar is from Unity. And the blue button is from my ARViewController. Both seem don't reach to touch event.
[image]

Debug elements:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean? If i debug the element, the unity view if wrapped inside UnityDefaultController, and in the same level with my button in ARViewController

Comment: I have integrated wikitude with same tutorial  and i am able to do everything

Comment: I manage to make it works. I don't know why.

Comment: you solve your issue ?

Comment: I just faced same issue from unity on some action all the view  are freeze so i managed it by ios buttons instead of using unity,

Comment: I have created button in native and get the action from unity -> Objc and On event on button send event back from objc -> unity from my project

Comment: Currently i just need to add back button on my navigation bar. I manage to do it. Thanks for your sharing, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Great you can post your answer and mark as accepted so other facing issue can get help :)

Comment: I'm still facing some problems though. When I go back and then open the ARViewController again, it blank. The startUnity() on appDelegate seems not called.

Comment: Issue is with `handleUnityReady` it will call only once !!! So your unity view is not added in so I suggest you to remove that observer and view will appear call that method manually

Comment: So, just call startUnity() in viewWillAppear and stopUnity() in viewWillDisappear? @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: You need to call show unity subview method in view will appear !!

Comment: And, when to call the startUnity()? I called it in viewWillAppear, and when I call showUnitySubview, there's blank. Do you mind sharing your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens when I put the Unity configuration at the top of `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, above my existing configuration for another services that I use in the project. For someone who encounter this problem in the future, here's my appDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    self.application = application

    // Another existing settings for the project, e.g. fabric

    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

    // Put the Unity configuration at the bottom of the function

    unity_init(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
    currentUnityController = UnityAppController()
    currentUnityController?.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    startUnity()
    stopUnity()

    return true
}
```

For the `viewWillAppear(_:)` in the view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setupBackBarButtonItems(back: true, isDark: true)
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        appDelegate.startUnity()
        showUnitySubView()
    }
}
```

As mentioned by @Prashant in the comment, the `UnityReady` notification only get called once. So I don't use it.

Then I just call `stopUnity()` in `viewWillDisappear(_:)`:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        appDelegate.stopUnity()
    }
}
```

The current problem is I can't kill the unity process if I leave the screen. It's known [bug](https://github.com/jiulongw/swift-unity/issues/25) and I'm still figuring out how to do that, if it's possible.

Comment: Good job , I found it earlier but just forgot to post !!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but moving Unity configuration to the end of `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOption` method didn't solve it and I still had a UIWindow in front of my screen that steals all user interactions.

My solution is not to create a new window in `UnityAppController.mm`, but using the current application keyWindow.

Replace:

```
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
```

with:

```
    _window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
```